# Filter problem: sprite does not dispatch MouseEvents anymore

Tags: actionscript-3, filter, mouseevent, sprite

I am dealing with a relly simple problem: after applying a BevelFilter to a sprite, it does not seem to dispatch MouseEvents anymore. I have tried to re-enable buttonMode, but with no luck. Am I missing something really elementary, or this is a Flash bug? It also occurs with the DropShadowFilter.

Edit: here is some code. It seems the problem comes from a combination from a mask and the filter:

```
        var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
        s.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
        s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
        s.buttonMode = true;
        s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        this.addChild(s);
        s.x = s.y = 100;
        var m:Sprite = new Sprite();
        m.graphics.beginFill(0,1);
        m.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
        s.addChild(m);

        // comment one of these two lines out and it works
        s.filters = [new BevelFilter()];
        s.mask = m;
```

I have tried to set mouseChildren, mouseEnabled and buttonMode of the mask to true, but with no result. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code please? No filter should cause this functionality on it's own, I'm not aware of any bug and have not encountered this bug/behavior in almost 5 years of working with flash

Comment: Ascension Systems and Aaron, thank you for your answers. I can only test it in a few hours and will let you know my results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried running your code and got the same result. Strange.

Anyway, I was able to make it work by creating a "container" sprite and applying the filter there:

```
var c:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(c);

var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
s.buttonMode = true;
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
c.addChild(s);
s.x = s.y = 100;
var m:Sprite = new Sprite();
m.graphics.beginFill(0,1);
m.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
s.addChild(m);

c.filters = [new BevelFilter()];
s.mask = m;
```

Would that solution work in your case?

Comment: Your answer is also correct but it's not because of a strange or unknown reason why his original code doesn't work. I posted the reason(s) in my answer. I'll upvote though because essentially you fixed the problem as well.

Comment: I'd add the reason to this answer if it gets chosen. The mask as a child was indeed the issue.

Comment: So I chose this answer because it simply works and of all other solutions I have tried, it causes the least boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to say exactly what the issue is without code. But setting :

```
mouseChildren = false;
```

Can at least eliminate some potential issues.

I don't believe that it is directly related to the BevelFilter, are you able to remove just the BevelFilter and it dispatches MouseEvents? I'd be surprised if that was the case.

Another thing to check - where is the eventListener set ? Is it possible that in some way you are not actually adding the eventListener in a given case ?

Really hard to do anything but theorize without code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problems seems to come from a combination of the filter and a mask. Here is some example code:

Comment: The code didn't show up in your comment Marc-Andre and that's a good thing anyway... can you please update your question to show some source code as per my & prototypical's request? We'd all love to help you but as prototypical has pointed out, all anyone can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the mask to be a child of the object you're trying to mask, and you're not setting the mask where the original object is. Here is the fixed code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1);
s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
s.buttonMode = true;
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
this.addChild(s);
s.x = s.y = 100;
var m:Sprite = new Sprite();
m.graphics.beginFill(0,1);
m.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
m.x = m.y = 100;
this.addChild(m);

// comment one of these two lines out and it works
s.filters = [new BevelFilter()];
s.mask = m;

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace('clicked');
}
```

Comment: Don't quote me 100% on this but I believe that a mask of an object must occupy the same scope (on the display list) as the target of the mask. For example, you cannot set the mask of a movieclip to be one of the children of that movieclip. I can see this being true because that would create a circular reference in the rendering code, telling the mask to mask itself.

Comment: I would agree that adding a clip's mask as its child may seem a bit strange, and perhaps it is not a best practice, but remember that the OP's code--which adds the mask as a child-- **works** as long as you don't add the filter. So simply adding the mask as a child, in and of itself, is not the problem.

Comment: Yes that is in fact the strange thing. I don't think that adding the mask as child to the masked element is causing this problem because I found this out: if you make the masked sprite just big enough (e.g. 400*400px) the problem goes away. Thank you anyway, Ascension Systems!